# Copying the whole content of the PDF File to the temporary file?

Tags: c#, pdf

Basically, I did ask already a question regarding on how to edit PDF File. But it seems that I need to pay a lot of money to achieve what I want. But here is the problem first,

I have a PDF Template containing a plain text like this {{Fullname}} like a placeholder and should be replaced with a certain value. Now, as I've said earlier, Editing the PDF File is a mess and tough because if it's not, I already saw a solution online for free.

Now, here is my Idea, What if I get the whole content of this template file and replace the placeholder with a certain value then create a new PDF File with the same content but the placeholder is already replaced?

I am trying to figure out this problem and here is my solution:

```
        string destinationFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string text = File.ReadAllText(sourceFile);
        text = text.Replace("{{Fullname}}", "John Doe");

        // Create a new PDF document
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(destinationFile, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        // Add the text to the document
        document.Add(new Paragraph(text));

        // Close the document
        document.Close();
```

Currently, I am using iTextSharp and does not meet what I expected. So, my question is, Is it possible to get all the content of the PDF File and modify it to create a new one? If yes, How?

Comment: PDF is a format created by Adobe. They have there own api's and libraries which aren't free .they have a pay as you go solution or bulk. You won't find any free ones out there. Unless you understand their specs. https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.7old.pdf You're going to be in trouble if they make any changes.

Comment: So basically, It is impossible to achieve that easy without paying, right?

Comment: so basically, yes it's not free. but most of them offers free trial period. ironPdf, asppdf, etc. 
in your case, I recommend having a razor template with whatever you want, then render the generated html as pdf. for building razor pages into html, you can use "Razor.Templating.Core" or similar. "Razor.Templating.Core" library doesn't provide caching but it's easy to make it work.

Comment: @Pamador, Thank you for this information. Actually, I am not using .Net Core due to my company technology. Currently, we are using WebForms.

Comment: that's fine, you just need to render your desired html(.net framework razor engine), then use one of those pdf rendering to render the generated html to pdf. 
https://ironpdf.com/blog/using-ironpdf/save-byte-array-to-pdf-csharp-tutorial/
i'm pretty sure you can make it work :)

Comment: you need to something like this:
        private readonly IRazorTemplateEngine _engine;

            var html = _engine.RenderAsync(($"/Views/templates/{template}.cshtml"), _myRequest);
            var (generatedData, numberOfPages) = GeneratePdf(html.Result.ToString());

inside GeneratePdf() method you use one of those package to render html to pdf, they're quite similar. 
IRazorTemplateEngine  will be your razor engine to render the razor pages to html

Comment: Is there a reason your company won't pay .05 cents per api call from adobe? That's actually the cheapest solution out there and the cost is dirt cheap. Unless your doing millions of calls to which it's probably cheaper in the long run to write your own from the specs above.

Comment: If your PDF file has no more than 10 pages, then you can check [Free Spire.PDF](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/free-pdf-component.html).